# Programming in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, wmi

Hey all I have a simple problem I was hoping someone can give me assistance with. I'm trying to get WMIC to return output however on different machines, the executable is in different directories. Is there a method to check all directories I list to get it to run, e.g.:

```
IF EXIST
wmic=c:\checkhere\
ELSE
wmic=c:\checkthisone\
CONTINUE
```

Comment: Can you tell us under which circumstances `wmic` resides not in its default location and/or its path is not present in the `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: I've tried:

SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM\
SET PATH=%PATH%

Which both failed. WMIC is installed in sys*32\wbem

operable program or batch file.
getting patch information
'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM\' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: By default `wmic` *is* in the PATH. It's also considered a good idea to leave the system PATH as it is (there are exceptions but most of he time they don't apply).

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple way of setting an environment variable to some path that has a file you are looking for.  A rather brain dead way but easy to understand/change:

```
if exist c:\path1\some.exe set asdf=c:\path1\
if exist c:\path2\some.exe set asdf=c:\path2\
if exist c:\path3\some.exe set asdf=c:\path3\
if %asdf%x=x goto couldnotfindit
set path=%path%;%asdf%
```

Answer (score 0):

As an option You could add all of them to the PATH variable and simply run `wmic`.